# Is it faster to follow relations in a query parameter or using model attribute lookup in Django Models?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, query-optimization

Say I have three Django Models:

- `User`,
- `Staff` which is one-to-one with `User`,
- `Thing` which is many-to-one with `Staff` on the 'owner' field.

Using a MySQL database, which of these performs better?

```
Thing.objects.filter(owner=user.staff)  # A
Thing.objects.filter(owner__user=user)  # B
```

What about if I am checking that the `Thing` that I want is owned by a `User`:

```
try:
    Thing.objects.get(id=some_id, owner=user.staff)  # D
    Thing.objects.get(id=some_id, owner__user=user)  # E
except Thing.DoesNotExist:
    return None
else:
    pass # do stuff

# Or F:
thing = Thing.objects.get(id=some_id)
if thing.owner.user != user:
    return None
pass # do stuff
```

Comment: You should try django debug toolbar or profiling your code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very much depends on how you got the original objects and what you've done with them since. If you've already accessed `user.staff`, or you originally queried User with `select_related`, then the first query is better as it is a simple SELECT on one table, whereas the second will do a JOIN to get to the User table.

However, if you have not already accessed `user.staff` and did not originally get it via `select_related`, the first expression will cause `user.staff` to be evaluated, which triggers a separate query, before even doing the Thing lookup. So in this case the second query will be preferable, since a single query with a JOIN is better than two simple queries.

Note however that this is almost certainly a micro-optimization and will have very little impact on your overall run time.

Answer (score 1):

Both those queries might end up as the same SQL, dependent on your settings, models, indexes and database driver.  You can verify that with the `.query` member variable.  If they differ the only real test will be empirical.  I can recommend [django-devserver](https://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver) and [ipython](http://ipython.org/) as profiling tools.

Answer (score 1):

```
Thing.objects.filter(owner=user.staff)  # A
Thing.objects.filter(owner__user=user)  # B
```

I ***think*** that the second one it "better". Assuming you've got the user record from the request:

- B will generate 1 SQL query only on Thing.
- I think A will generate a query for user.staff and then one on Thing. (also that might take more memory for the staff instance)

---

To be sure try this and inspect the timing and the generated queries with the debug toolbar:

```
for i in range(0, 100):
    things = Thing.objects.filter(owner=user.staff)  # A
    #things = Thing.objects.filter(owner__user=user)  # B

    # that will execute the queries
    for thing in things.all():
         print thing.name
```

Then replace with B...